# One-liner is SASS

Tags: css, sass

In CSS I can do something like this:

```
.apple  { background-image: url('apple.png'); }
.orange { background-image: url('orange.png'); }
.pear   { background-image: url('pear.png'); }
```

but it seems in sass (not scss) the same would take up 6 lines? Is it possible to do a one-liner is sass for rules that only have one property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sass syntax is principally based on indentation and line breaks, so in Sass that would indeed be six lines (two per rule, excluding blank lines):

```
.apple
    background-image: url('apple.png')

.orange
    background-image: url('orange.png')

.pear
    background-image: url('pear.png')
```

As far as I've seen you can't condense those to one-liners in Sass.

Comment: Your SASS is going to get compiled in to minified CSS anyway

Comment: The motivation was more for code organization and seeing more on a single screen

Answer (score 7):

This isn't by any means meant to help you condense this code to one line, but to think of it from a different perspective.

In this post on The Sass Way titled ["Sass control directives: @if, @for, @each and @while"](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while), I cover control directives in Sass. Here's a way to write your code using the @each directive.

```
$fruit-list: apple orange pear

=fruit
  @each $fruit in $fruit-list
    &.#{$fruit}
      background-image: url(#{$fruit}.png)

.fruit
  +fruit
```

Which outputs:

```
.fruit.apple {
  background-image: url(apple.png);
}
.fruit.orange {
  background-image: url(orange.png);
}
.fruit.pear {
  background-image: url(pear.png);
}
```

Using .scss we can make this a one liner, but at the cost of readability of the code:

```
$fruit-list: apple orange pear;

@mixin fruit { @each $fruit in $fruit-list { &.#{$fruit} { background-image: url(#{$fruit}.png); } } }

.fruit { @include fruit; }
```